# Algorithms behind Algorithmic Tree or Plant Growing

Tags: algorithm, 3d

What are all the algorithms involved in Farmville game, specifically I am interested in drawing trees that has fruits based on user's activities.

I am into a project which has a specific need to draw a tree-type image in SVG. I am not sure how to go about the algorithms to define the tree and based on certain business rules the leafs in the tree grows etc., I think you get the idea. Farmville is just an example I took to explain.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Whoa, I find it very unlikely that FarmVille uses any kind of advanced "algorithm" to draw SVG images. I'm guessing they just have a collection of stock images (like, 3 or 4) for the various stages in a tree's development. Don't you think?

Comment: As i said, FarmVille is just an example to make question self explanatory, Now I am thinking I should remove that word. I basically wanted to have a tree drawn using SVG and get it grow based on some rules.

Comment: Any sane computer sprite-based game has a set of premade tree sprites, without any advanced technologies for tree rendering. If a tree has fruits on it, then fruits are simply additional sprites, placed at predefined locations. If you want advanced tree rendering, you should google for old nvidia "GL tree" demo, and "SPeed tree alternatives". All that stuff is 3 dimensional, but may give you some ideas.

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading if you're looking for algorithms governing dynamic plant growth and not Farmville's tree sprites' implementation.  I'd suggest rewording at least your title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comments above show the case for a simple sprite based tree. This is what most systems will use. I fail to see how business rules apply - perhaps you also need a factory interface factory ;).

If you are actually interested in programatically generating natural systems, I suggest looking at [L-systems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) [The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop) is also a fantastic reference book (made available as a PDF as its out of print)

Comment: L-systems. Great reference. Thanks.